# how can I convert normal javascript function to export?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, export

I have one library which I need to export in project but it's written in javascript functions. I want to export and import into my multiple projects.

```
function BlurImage( imageID, canvasID, radius, blurAlphaChannel, iterations ){

var img = document.getElementById( imageID );
var w = img.naturalWidth;
var h = img.naturalHeight;
   debugger;
var canvas = document.getElementById( canvasID );
  debugger;
canvas.style.width  = w + "px";
canvas.style.height = h + "px";
canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.clearRect( 0, 0, w, h );
context.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );

if ( isNaN(radius) || radius < 1 ) return;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to use a package management system in your projects, such as [Bower](https://bower.io/). It's simple to get started with, and has easy getting started instructions on the front page of their web site.

If your code needs to be private, it's possible for you to store your functions in a private git repository and import them into your project. See [this post](http://www.frontendjunkie.com/2014/01/using-bower-as-package-management-tool.html) for information on how to do that.

Comment: Bower seems a bit outdate IMOd. That aside, I'm guessing they want to include their code as a standalone JS file in the browser (ie such as bundled & minified jQuery files from a CDN), not as, say a Node project with NPM or Bower.

Answer (score 0):

You can export a function by adding export keyword before the function.

If you want to export several functions per file, use following syntax:

```
    export function A () {...};
    export function B () {...};
```

If you want to export one function per module, use default keyword:

```
    export default function A () {...};
```

You can also combine both strategies of exporting functions in the same file. Sometimes you might want one export per module but might want to test other functions.

```
    export default function A () {...};
    export function B () {...};
```

You can now import the functions into other files

```
    import {A, B} from 'filename.js'; // non default functions
    import A from 'filename.js'; // default function
    import A, {B} from 'filename.js'; // combine default and non-default
```

Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: I tried export function A () { }; and import { A } form 'filenam.js'. it still gives the same error.

Comment: There is a typo. Its from not form. Also, what does the error message say?

Comment: Could not find a declaration file for module 'filename.js'.

Comment: This just means that it is not able to find the file. Make sure to use the right path that points to that file.